# Problem with MySQL query with days and time range

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have these tables:

- machines(id)
- products(id, name)
- machine_products(id, machine_id [FK], product_id [FK], price)
- machine_product_restrictions(id, machine_product_id [FK], day, begin_hour, end_hour)

Explanations:

- For 1 'machine' I have N 'machine_product'
- For 1 'product' I have N 'machine_product'
- For 1 'machine' and 1 'product' I have 1 'machine_product'
- For 1 'machine_product' I have N 'machine_product_restriction'
- One 'machine_product_restriction' belongs to 1 'machine_product'
- Could be N 'machine_product_restrictions' for 1 'machine_product' with same day and diferent time range.

**What I want of query**

Simply I want unique products of a specific machine (machine_id=1) available NOW (for this day of week [1-monday, 7-sunday], and for this time/hour [HH:mm - 24h]) with name and price.

**What I tried**

```
SELECT P.id, P.name, MP.price FROM products P
JOIN machine_products MP on MP.product_id = P.id
LEFT JOIN machine_product_restrictions R on MP.id = R.machine_product_id
WHERE MP.machine_id = 1
AND 
(
    R.machine_product_id IS NULL 
    OR
    (
        R.machine_product_id IS NOT NULL
        &&
        (R.DAY = DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) -1) 
        &&
        (TIME(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN TIME(R.begin_hour) AND TIME(R.end_hour)) 
    )
)
```

This don't work at all because returns me repeated products as 'machine_product_restrictions' are out of now time range.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)